# bootstrap 3 contact form misbehave

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing a site with a contact form for that purpose I chose [this codepen example](http://codepen.io/jaycbrf/pen/iBszr) of bootstrap 3 contact form with validation.
This form works fine but an error occurs when I implement php code and attempt to insert form values into a MySQL database.
The problem is when I fill all fields and try to submit, submit button disabled like when an error occurred, but if I resubmit any one value and try to submit it's done. I thought and thought but can't troubleshoot any reason. I decide to take this issue before experts like you because I am not an expert.

Everything I have done so far can be found live at [this link](http://pendantyourname.com/database/insert3.php).

My javascript and php code is bellow.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
    // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        first_name: {
            validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                    min: 2,
                },
                    notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your first name'
                }
            }
        },
         last_name: {
            validators: {
                 stringLength: {
                    min: 2,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your last name'
                }
            }
        },
        pendant_name: {
            validators: {
                 stringLength: {
                    min: 2,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your pendant name'
                }
            }
        },
        confirm_pendant_name: {
            validators: {
                 stringLength: {
                    min: 2,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please confirm your pendant name'
                },
            }
        },
        email: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your email address'
                },
                emailAddress: {
                    message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
                }
            }
        },
        phone: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your phone number'
                },
                phone: {
                    country: 'US',
                    message: 'Please supply a vaild phone number with area code'
                }
            }
        },
        address: {
            validators: {
                 stringLength: {
                    min: 8,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your street address'
                }
            }
        },
        city: {
            validators: {
                 stringLength: {
                    min: 4,
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your city'
                }
            }
        },
        country: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please select your country'
                }
            }
        },
        state: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please select your state'
                }
            }
        },
        zip: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please supply your zip code'
                },
                zipCode: {
                    //country: 'US',
                    message: 'Please supply a vaild zip code'
                }
            }
        },
        }
    })

    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
      $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow"); // Do something ...

       $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }, 'json');
});
});
```

here is my php code.

```
<?php
//Establishing Connection with Server
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "myusername", "mypassword");

//Selecting Database from Server
$db = mysql_select_db("mydbname", $connection);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$pendant_name = $_POST['pendant_name'];
$confirm_pendant_name = $_POST['confirm_pendant_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$query = mysql_query("insert into mytable(first_name, last_name, pendant_name, confirm_pendant_name, email, phone, address, country, state, city, zip) values ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$pendant_name', '$confirm_pendant_name', '$email','$phone', '$address', '$country', '$state', '$city', '$zip' )");
}
//Closing Connection with Server
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: can you please put your error while submitting your form, plz update the error as well in your question.

Comment: Set ```error_reporting(-1);``` at the first line of your php script and upload it to your server. Open developer tools in your favorite browser. There you can see all ajax request under the network tab. When you press the submit button you should see error in network tab log. Maybe you are just putting values you can't insert to your database for example.

Comment: @Northys 

I have **set error_reporting(-1);**  as you mentioned and uploaded on the server and did all as you mentioned but I can't get any error. Please check it yourself perhaps you can identify any error.

Comment: @waseem the problem is in your javascript, it does not even reach the ajax state so problem is not in your php. I'm not good at javascript at all so I was not able to debug it, sorry. I think I could get it running with http://formvalidation.io/ (I don't know what Bootstrap Validator actually is). I don't have so many time right now though.

Comment: @waseem, where is your html page, is the program a total copy of the codepen example ?

Comment: @RSN there is link in the question http://pendantyourname.com/database/insert3.php